# How to implement tracing of wavy lines in a 2d greyscale 8bit image?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

I have a project where I need to precisely trace non-straight lines in a 2d image.

I started trying to solve the issue using OpenCV.

There's an image of a graph with multiple paths (wavy lines) in a 2d image, and I need to generate an array of (x,y) coordinates of the various lines.

I need to generate a separate array of (x,y) coordinates for each line.

I'm looking for a method of differentiating the lines from each other.

[image: Here is an example of the type of image I'm talking about]

The issue is that with the 2d image that I'm working with, all of the lines are in one image, so I need to differentiate them myself.

**The information I have for differentiating the lines in my graph is:**

1. The lines are **continuous** (max 1 dead pixel horizontal gap, max 20 pixel jump in vertical gap)
2. The lines are all somewhat **horizontal**, always traveling positively along the X axis.
3. Lines are thin. Up to (and including) **4 pixels width**.
4. The thickness and brightness of each line **doesn't vary** abruptly.
5. the slope of the line changes **gradually**, never any sharp turns.
6. Any lines could abruptly **terminate**.
7. There could be up to **20 lines** in every vertical slice of the image.
8. Noise in the image is insignificant.
9. When lines overlap, the brightness increases at the point that they're overlapping.

I can easily solve the issue myself with a paper and pencil, so I know that it can be done.

The image dimensions are 1008 height, 2048 width. The computation is allowed to take up to 5 seconds on a modern desktop computer.

This has to be done programmatically, and accurately. I need to know the precise heights of each line. I'm allowed to hard-code values for my specific data.

This is the code I have so far in OpenCV:

```
    std::uint8_t* img_2d_8bit_row_major;
....
....
    cv::Mat orig_img(size,CV_8UC1,img_2d_8bit_row_major);
    cv::imshow("original image", orig_img);
    cv::waitKey(0);
    cv::Mat canny_output;
    cv::Canny(as_image, canny_output, 6.0, 30.0, 3, true);
    cv::imshow("canny", canny_output);
    cv::waitKey(0);
```

The above code works in converting my image into a binary black/white image

but that's not enough for line tracing.

Comment: Looks like you have 2 problems: 1) tracing a line, 2) differentiating lines by thickness/brightness so you can resolve lines crossing at narrow angles.

Comment: I do not think there is any way to determine which direction a line goes when you have cross-overs or two lines touch each other. How would you know whether the line continues down or bounces up?

Comment: @fmw42 I figure that in 99% of cases I can differentiate the overlapping lines with my own eyes and brain. Therefore it should be possible for a computer to do the same.

Comment: Only if you give it rules to determine which path to follow.